# List all categories that have results in a query

Tags: filters, taxonomy, query

I have an archive page that I am building multi-filtering for. The archive page lists paginated results from a custom post type, and there are 3000 posts within it.

I would like to be able to filter this post type by two taxonomies, but importantly the page should only show an option to filter by one of the categories within each taxonomy if there is a result.

The below code works, but is extremely slow and inefficient, taking five seconds to return results. How can I improve this or are there alternative solutions to implement multi-filtering?

```
$tax_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'output',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '2000',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($tax_args);
$all_terms = array();

if($the_query->have_posts()):
    while($the_query->have_posts()):
    $the_query->the_post(); 

        $terms = wp_get_post_terms($the_query->post->ID, array('library-topics', 'library-types'));
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $all_terms[] = $term->name;
        }

    endwhile;   
    $result = array_unique($all_terms);
    foreach ($result as $term){
        echo $term . '<br/>';
    }
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: 2,000 posts per page is always going to take awhile to grab. I would look into caching and perhaps transients so that at least the initial unfiltered query would be served from a cache or transient, instead of always having to run an enormous query.

Comment: Thanks, these results are rarely run but often updated, so I don't think caching is the right solution, without updating the cache on every new post – seems like a much bigger job than I'm looking to implement. Are there any more efficient ways of accessing this data eg. get_categories or equivalent?